# two div in a line one is having image

Tags: html, css, css-float

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kmJe/) I would like the "Delete" and "Update" buttons to appear in the correct position instead of below the image.

Please suggest how it can be done.

**Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/2kmJe/2/) example**

Comment: You want what now? You need to rephrase your question, this is barely understandable. Where exactly do you want your buttons? What have you tried so far? Why do you have random Firebug links in the middle of your CSS? Please help us to help you by clearing up your questions a bit :)

Comment: @Kyle Please check the link of fiddle :)

Comment: Please don't copy-paste code from Firebug. It's impossible to read and it breaks in your case e.g. your example CSS. Here's a clean(er) version: http://jsfiddle.net/2kmJe/1/

Comment: @Rahul Mehta: Please fix your jsFiddle - you randomly have `styles.css (line 948)` in the middle of your CSS.

Comment: @polarblau okay next time want take care

Comment: @Rahul Mehta: "i want delete and update button to come in the right position" - what is the *right position*?

Comment: I suggest you to clean up the markup first...

Comment: @Andreyco it is the cleaner http://jsfiddle.net/2kmJe/1/

Comment: @all sorry for poor english want to improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the image and the buttons to float positioning mode!

For example, check this example out: http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/77bdN/

this is your example forked : http://jsfiddle.net/vVtBt/ (you have to set a width on the image)

Comment: image can have variable size , and i have already given please check http://jsfiddle.net/2kmJe/1/

Comment: image can have variable width :)

Comment: the container has a fixed size, so if the image width is > than an X width the buttons will go below the image. You should set a width, or better a max-width for the <img> element ;)

Comment: Rahul, if you set the width of that image via css, the proportions will be maintained! 
If you don't set a width, the image can "overflow" and then your inputs will go below that image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set fixed width for the floating elements, you also misplaced the `clear` CSS... clean and working version of your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/2kmJe/3/

The trick was setting width to both `div` elements with float.